# Using createElement('img') to get .jpeg instead of .png

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use createElement("img') to create .jpeg extension instead of .png

[According to Flanagan's book JavaScript: The Definitive Guide: Activate Your Web Pages By David Flanagan,](http://books.google.ca/books?id=4RChxt67lvwC&lpg=PA685&ots=tgW8zlOSt7&dq=createelement%20javascript%20img%20jpg%20definitive%20guide&pg=PA866#v=onepage&q=png&f=false)

> For jpeg image type, the second argument should be a number between 0
>   and 1 specifying the image quality level.

I am not sure what the syntax for the code would be.

Is it something like this?

```
createElement("img",1)
```

Comment: When you create an <img> element, it doesn't actually create an image.  It creates an HTML element that can hold an image.  You have to then specify the path to that image.

What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You really have to buy the book to get that previous page, because there is no "type" attribute to createElement.  Flanagan is referring to a different function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book is talking about html5's canvas tag and specifically its .toDataURL method.

I think you want to do something like:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'myImageSource.jpg';
```

In this case, it's up to the web server to deliver the image and its type information to the web browser.

Comment: If I wanted jpeg, would it be `img.src = 'myImageSource.JPEG';`

Comment: @garbagecollection, it depends on what you've saved the image as? Usually JPG files are saved as `your_file_name.jpg`, although you'll need to check.

Comment: Yes I was a bit misleading there, fixed (changed fake filename to .jpg)

Answer (score 3):

[The book](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement) that you're referring to seems to be talking about the `toDataURL` method of the `canvas` API ([see this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement)), which accepts `type` and `quality` arguments.

You can use `document.createElement` without worrying about MIME types or quality.

Answer (score 0):

you can use setAttrebure() Method or built-in 'src' property.

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttibute('src', 'img.jpg');
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

or use

```
 var img = document.createElement('img');
 img.src = "img.jpg";
 document.body.appendChild(img);
```